# What is the best way to get locally installed maven dependency on ec2 (AWS)?

Tags: maven

I am building a project and deploying it on ec2 (aws). I want to break my project into multiple packages, each of which are maven dependencies. I can use these dependencies in my service (which i am deploying on the ec2 host) locally by registering these packages in local repository. This setup works well locally but when I deploy it on ec2, it is not able to find these local dependencies listed in service pom.xml file. Now the reason for this is obvious, the other packages i have created are not on any public repository, I have seen the method to add them on public maven repositories but I feel its too much effort, doing this for all the packages will take a lot of time and is not scalable. Is there any other way I can solve this problem? Are there public repositories where uploading the artifact is simple and won't have any waiting period?

Comment: So you are running your builds on ec2? Do you have a Jenkins installed on aws, or which other way to you use?

Comment: @JFMeier I am using aws code pipeline and aws code build

Comment: Since nobody else comments, let me add: I do not know about the cloud, but in a traditional setting, you would use a build server (like your aws code build) and also a Nexus/Artifactory server that hosts the artifacts for you. This would be the place the build server reads from and writes to. Depending on where your code is: I read that github/gitlab offer you some form of Maven repositories as well.

Comment: @JFMeier hey turns out we can use S3 as private repository, i also found a free website https://mymavenrepo.com/ which allows 1 private repo upto 256 mb and the setup is very simple